# Automator Preferences

Tags: applescript, automator

I am using Lion OSX and I want to make an automator service that will toggle the scroll-direction preferences.
Because I also use a Wacom Tablet, the scroll-direction screws up my panning, so I wanted to create Automator service that toggles by keystroke. However the "WatchMeDoIt" takes forever to function, how do you make this work (applescript? or what?)

Thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
on run {} --put whatever is appropriate here
    tell application "System Preferences"
        activate
        set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.trackpad"
    end tell

    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences"
           click radio button "Scroll & Zoom" of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
           click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
       end tell
    end tell

    tell application "System Preferences" to quit
end run
```

This should do it. :)